# Need help in converting perl RegExp query to sed one

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed, grep

I have written perl script for parsing input text/file as follow:

```
[root@agent tmp]# head ./test_regqexp_keynote.txt
alert@keynote.com       (Top20) Carnation GB/fd (Crit)  9:57    11 KB
alert@keynote.com       (Shell Brand EUR) HealthScience NL/fd (Crit)    9:36
11 KB
alert@keynote.com       (Shell Corp AMS) Nestle JP/fd (Crit)    9:16    11 KB
alert@keynote.com       (Top20) NestleHealth DE/fd (Crit)       9:01    11 KB
alert@keynote.com       (Shell Corp AMS) Nestle NZ/fd (Crit)    8:17    12 KB
alert@keynote.com       (Shell Brand EUR) HealthScience CH/fd (Crit)    8:11
11 KB
alert@keynote.com       (Shell Corp AMS) Nestle CL/fd (Crit)    8:11    11 KB
alert@keynote.com       (Shell Corp AMS) Nestle VE/fd (Crit)    8:11    11 KB
```

and getting text as follow on output:

```
HealthScience FI/fd
DolceGusto NZ/fd
Waters WW/fd
Nestle UA/fd
Nestle SK/fd
Nestle SI/fd

perl -ne 'if ($_=~ m/([a-zA-Z]* [A-Z]{2,3}\/fd)/) {print "$1\n";}'
```

So just extract of part "XXXX XX/fd".

But I need it to be done using SED tool.

And it made me crazy. Seems that SED works in totally different way or has very different rules of RegEx.

Please help me to convert this RegExp query to SED RegExp query. Or explain what is mainly different in Sed RegExp from Perl or Egrep RegExp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n 's#.* \([a-zA-Z]* [A-Z]\{2,3\}/fd\).*#\1#p' test_regqexp_keynote.txt
```

Or:

```
egrep -o '[a-zA-Z]* [A-Z]{2,3}/fd' test_regqexp_keynote.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
sed -n 's!.* \([a-zA-Z]* [A-Z]\{2,3\}/fd\).*!\1!p' input
```

and perhaps this may work too:

```
sed -n 's!.* \([^ ]* [^ ]*/fd\).*!\1!p' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of complicated regex, you can try this `awk`

```
awk -F"[)] | [(]" 'NF>3{print $3}' file
Carnation GB/fd
HealthScience NL/fd
Nestle JP/fd
NestleHealth DE/fd
Nestle NZ/fd
HealthScience CH/fd
Nestle CL/fd
Nestle VE/fd
```

Comment: Can you please explaine how this field separator works/parsed by AWK?

-F"[)] | [(]"

I thought we should point here only 1 sign like : or ( or what ever.

Comment: @user2273663 You can use any regex in `FS` filed separator, and on `gnu awk` you can do the same in `RS`. The `|` is an or. So here you get `) ` or ` (` as separators. Since parentheses are special command in regex, and escaping does not work `\(`, we use bracket  `[(]`. Eks: `[a-c]|12` give `a` `b` `c` and `12` as separator.

Comment: @user2273663 If you like my answer, you can give +1

Comment: @user2273663, I wish I could give you +1. I tried. Got message that I don;t have enough of reputation yet. ((